# WCF Data Services (OData) deployment on IIS 5.1

Tags: wcf, iis, service

I have developed a WCF Data service using VS 2010, I am able to run it and get the data as feed by running using VS 2010.

I published the service on IIS 5.1 but I m getting http: 404 error.

Can anyone help to deploy the service on IIS 5.1 step by step?

Answer (score 0):

I found a bit on it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/25200fa5-09bc-4052-94ae-281eb8300763/).